# UITextView vs UILabel+ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uitextview, core-text

Im working on a an app that requires a view Controller to display a nice amount of hebrew(non-english) text in it.

*The text is an AttributedString from a Rich Text File*

There are 4 things that I need the view to do.

1. Smooth Scrolling
2. Get the range of a word so I can auto-scroll to it (like `scrollRangeToVisible`)
3. Change the font smoothly (I'd like to use a UISlider to change the font)
4. Load quickly

In a sense Im looking for the capabilities of a e-reader just I only need one column and I want it to scroll not page.

Things I've tried and there pros and cons

**Regular UITextView & Scrollview Classed as UITextView**

PROS:

- Easy search and auto-scroll
- Quick load
- Smooth font changing

CON:

- Very choppy scrolling

**UILabel in a ScrollView**

PROS:

- search and auto-scroll is not easy but manageable
- Very smooth scrolling

CON:

- Very choppy font switching
- Slow loading

The only thing I haven't tried (that I can think of) is *CoreText*

Is coreText the way to go? I would rather use a UITextView if there as a way to get it to render lots of hebrew (non-english) text better.

*Note: I have already tried disabling editing on the UITextView and Selectable.*

**EDIT 1**

```
-(double)Height{
    [layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
    NSLog(@"HEIGHT = %f",[layoutManager
                          usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer].size.height);
    return [layoutManager
            usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer].size.height;
}
```

Comment: did you verify that its the hebrew text thats causing the problem? Try with a similar size rich text document with english?

Comment: I honestly never even thought about it but yes i confirmed its the Hebrew text. I tried with [Objective-C wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) and it scrolled perfect.

Comment: Are you only going to be displaying the hebrew text? No selection/editing etc?

Comment: Ya I don't need the selection or editing features but as I stated at the end of my question, Ive already tried with them off/disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I would

Create an NSTextStorage(an NSAttributedString) object with the hebrew text.

Create NSLayoutManager object, NSTextContainer. Hook them up.

[Render](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/DrawingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001808-CJBGBIBB) them onto a custom UIView with a size that you can query from the NSLayoutManager like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001809-CJBGBIBB).

Implementing scrollRangeToVisible will be a good task in itself. I would use one of [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:effectiveRange:) methods.

If you only have the character range and need to compute glyph range, one of [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/glyphRangeForCharacterRange:actualCharacterRange:) methods could help.

This won't be very easy, but a very good project :)

Comment: I will try this just 2 question. 1) The links you sent were for Mac, they will work for iPhone/IOS as well? 2) How would I search & auto-Scroll with this? Does scrollRangeToVisible work here as well? Thanks

Comment: Also I assume i attach this UIView to a Scrollview?

Comment: @user2738258 Yes it will work for iOS. They are almost the same. Implementing scrollRangeToVisible will be a good task in itself. I would use one of [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:effectiveRange:) methods. Yes the view goes inside the scroll view.

Comment: @user2738258 yes. I provided more links in my answer. If you complete this solution, you should add it to cocoapods.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and see what happens

Comment: How do you set the textAlignment with NSLayouManager

Comment: Also how do I change Font size ? Do I have to loop through the attributes of the attributedString?

Comment: Im also having trouble resizing the UIView.. The words appear on screen but the view isn't resizing. I tried using the link (SEE EDIT IN POST) but I'm sure I'm doing it wrong

Comment: @user2738258 since your original question is about UILabel and UITextView and you have moved onto NSLayoutManager, for bookkeeping can you post them as new questions? I will look at them tomorrow morning.

Comment: I moved the question to here: [Stack Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672601/fitting-nslayoutmanager-into-uiview)

Comment: Please take a look at the question. I honestly have tried so hard to figure this out and I just can't. Its driving me insane